# Drupal views module ask for GB of RAM and lead to white page

Tags: 7, views

I set memory_limit  as -1 in my php.ini. Drupal exhausted it all apparently and when i dump the memory limit with ini_get, it give 8GB. Even with this confortable resource, it cannot fullfill the request :

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 20971520) (tried to allocate 1717530240 bytes) in C:\AltaV2Drupal\src\main\drupal\sites\all\modules\contrib\views\modules\image.views.inc on line 28
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0006  358328  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
2   0.0089  361952  drupal_bootstrap( ) ...\index.php:23
3   0.0835  1297480 _drupal_bootstrap_full( )   ...\bootstrap.inc:2523
4   2.3001  4800256 menu_set_custom_theme( )    ...\common.inc:5301
5   2.3001  4800256 menu_get_custom_theme( )    ...\menu.inc:1780
6   2.3492  4810968 menu_get_item( )    ...\menu.inc:1765
7   2.3517  4810992 menu_rebuild( ) ...\menu.inc:468
8   2.3594  4812928 menu_router_build( )    ...\menu.inc:2775
9   4.1009  11234688    views_ui_menu( )    ...\menu.inc:2812
10  4.1009  11235504    views_get_all_templates( )  ...\views_ui.module:33
11  4.1185  11250128    node_views_templates( ) ...\views.module:1395
12  4.1250  11259832    views_db_object->new_display( ) ...\node.views_template.inc:24
13  4.1251  11259832    views_db_object->add_display( ) ...\view.inc:2431
14  4.1251  11259832    views_fetch_plugin_data( )  ...\view.inc:2335
15  4.1258  11326056    _views_fetch_plugin_data( ) ...\views.module:1304
16  4.1550  11349528    views_discover_plugins( )   ...\cache.inc:145
17  4.1595  11350584    entity_views_plugins( ) ...\plugins.inc:414
18  4.1652  11350624    views_fetch_data( ) ...\entity.views.inc:320
19  4.1652  11350624    _views_fetch_data( )    ...\views.module:1293
20  4.1665  11350696    _views_fetch_data_build( )  ...\cache.inc:75
21  4.1665  11350696    module_invoke_all( )    ...\cache.inc:90
22  6.4209  14253608    field_views_data( ) ...\module.inc:963
23  8.1812  17633680    module_invoke( )    ...\field.views.inc:32
24  8.1813  17633952    image_field_views_data( )   ...\module.inc:926
```

I use acquiadev environnement on windows, with drupal 7.51, php 7.0.

Any hints ?

Comment: It sounds like you might have a view that returns a giant amount of data - one thing to try would be disabling auto Views preview so that when you open a view to edit, it isn't executing and returning / rendering data. Otherwise, need to know more about the View.

Comment: Me neither ! I cannot access any page of the site or the admin side ...

Comment: Do you have a pages set, and are you using rendered entities or fields for output?  I may know what is happening if so.

Comment: Is it a new Page? Can u uninstall Views module? Disabling can be easy achived directly in db

Comment: @mpdonadio : yes, i confirm, we render entities for output ! We use a dozaine of entities with some are sharing fields. Some fields use views reference and reciprocally.

Comment: @Benone_ : the problem arised after i added two new fields to an entity. Coincidence or direct cause ? I will try to access again admin page to apply kevin idea of disabling auto views preview

Comment: @sssimon Could you post the view export?